# Control scale dependent visibility of symbols created using geometry generator in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS v3.2 "Bonn".

I currently have symbols that have labels and call-out lines created using the geometry generator. I can make the labels follow scale dependent visibility rules, and would like to have the call-out lines follow the same rules but haven't found a way to do so.

Is there a way to set scale dependent visibility for such objects? Below is the geometry generator interface.

[image: Geometry generator interface]

Comment: What about using an `if` statement in your expression which only generates the objects if they're within a certain map scale threshold: e.g. `if(@map_scale < 10000, make_line(...), None)`

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, that worked for me! Should I create an answer with that code?

Comment: It would be great if you did! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Joseph for the suggestion, by adding an if statement to the code I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do.

Code for the geometry generator is as follows:

```
if(@map_scale < 200000, 
  make_line(
    make_point($x, $y),
    make_point(("auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx"), ("auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony"))
  ),
None
)
```